# jquery chosen overlaps other ui elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I recently found the chosen plugin for dropdown lists and I really like the way it makes filtering really easy.

I have a problem with it though. I have a menu on the top of my site that unfolds when I hover it and the submenus go "under" my select-chosen element.

[image]

I don't know if it's clear enough but it's a big problem.
Any idea of what I need to modify to get it working properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out. 
I needed to add a z-index value on my menus so it always appears on top.